# How to add a second module to GAE?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have followed the docs to create an additional B2 module to my existing default F1 instance.

app.yaml (default instance)

```
application: myapp-uat
version: 1-7-0
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 2
  max_pending_latency: 1s
threadsafe: true

- url: .*
  script: run.myapp.app
```

and the new module:

```
application: myapp-uat
module: backend
version: 1.0.0
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

instance_class: B2
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

- url: /generator
  script: run.myapp.app
  login: admin
```

I have updated the app like this:

```
appcfg.py update src app.yaml backend.yaml
```

However looking at my modules in dashboard, I only see the default instance.  Something isn't quite right here.

[image]

Comment: can you show the output/log of the `appcfg.py update` cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I had done something quote silly. The correct way would be:

```
appcfg.py update src/app.yaml src/backend.yaml
```

and last but not least the dispatch needs to be called:

```
appcfg.py update_dispatch src
```